# while creating custom module upgrade command not working and all other commands not working before it works at the time of magento2 installation

Tags: magento2, command-line

its showing one message-

Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements.html

[image]

Comment: Please check your php version and magento version

Comment: Kindly check magento log file as well.